# center to the div in all cases

Tags: html, css

How can i center the .tag_closet div into the middle when they are dinamic (part of a loop) ? sometimes i have 2 .tag_closet divs and sometimes more is there a way to center to the middle all divs in all cases ? right now they all start appearing from the top.
i want the result to by like this :[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBhpS.jpg)

```css
.closet_border {background:lightgray;height:100px;width:300px;clear:both}
.tag_closet  {
  
  background: #df1b57 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px lightgray;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    
}
```

```html
<div  class="closet_border"> <div class="tag_closet">1 Calçao</div>   <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
<div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div><div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div><div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: using margin:auto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, where I added a wrapper

```
.closet_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.closet_border {background:lightgray;height:100px;width:300px;clear:both}
.tag_closet  {
  background: #df1b57 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px lightgray;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.closet_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div  class="closet_border">
  <div  class="closet_wrapper">
    <div class="tag_closet">1 Calçao</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is another, using `display: table`

```css
.closet_border {background:lightgray;height:100px;width:300px;clear:both
    display: table;
}
.tag_closet  {
  background: #df1b57 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px lightgray;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.closet_wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div  class="closet_border">
  <div  class="closet_wrapper">
    <div class="tag_closet">1 Calçao</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
    <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE9 and earlier I would suggest you to use the [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) model.

Try this:

```
.closet_border {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  clear: both;

  /* flex container */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* force child items to line break */
  justify-content: center; /* child elements horizontally centered */
  align-content: center; /* concentrate child elements in the vertical center of container */
  align-items: center; /* child elements vertically centered */
}

.tag_closet {
  background: #df1b57;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px lightgray; /* why this? */
  color: white;
  /*float: left;*/ /* you don't need this with display flex */
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; /*11px*/
  margin: 3px 4px; /* better use of margin */
  padding: 4px;

  /* flex items */
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/reatlat/pen/QNEJeo)
Hope it helps!

```css
.closet_border {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  clear: both;
}

.tag_closet {
  background: #df1b57 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px lightgray;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="closet_border">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="tag_closet">1 Calçao</div>
            <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
            <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
            <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
            <div class="tag_closet">1 JumpSuit</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `table`/`tr`/`td` elements is really not for creating layouts, it's for list data.